# why web templates are in .xml format even when they are written in html

Tags: html, xml, web

May look silly but I am new to web development.Can anybody tell me why web templates are in .xml format even when they are written in html.Also how to manage new web pages by using predefined template.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Feel free to use a space after punctuation.

Comment: I'll make sure to follow the rules next time :).